# Convert to Curves option gives me different hair shape

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I'm using Bezeir curves to create hair curves, than converting them into hair by right clicking and selecting Covert to curve:

[image]

However, when I do so, all the curviness is gone and I even have straight lines now.  This probably due to the points per curve option being defaulted to 8. So my question is:

Is there a way to change this value?  I know I can do it in sculpt mode, I don't want that, I want to make my Bezeir curves then convert them using this feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could selecting all of the curves, going into edit mode, and then right click/F3>Subdivide work? Try this before and after converting

Comment: Does not.  Still gives me same result after I had 20 sub divisions.

See my edited post.